# I want to know how to manage categories in dynamodb

Tags: firebase, nosql, bigdata, amazon-dynamodb, categories

I wanna know how to manage categories in dynamodb. I have 3 depth categories and managing like 'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'. But I think this is old. I want to make categories array field becasue of expedability.

But there is a big problem. I would treat big-data, and if I use categories array, I would scan all of contents and there would be long time issue. Is there good method to query array data? If no, is there good method any other Nosql db like firebase?

Comment: You mean query array data without the partition key?

Comment: Yes, I don't want use three category index. I want use one array category index, and want not use scan...